# which product should I use between wso2 emm and mdm roadmap

Tags: wso2

EMM is built with jaggery.js, and MDM is built with java. 
And EMM1.1.0 is released last year, MDM2.0 is released on this year.

From all the document that I read, I should use EMM. But I didn't see any development activity on EMM.

And also jaggery.js is still in 0.9 beta, 0.10.1 is still in snapshot version.

I just need MDM features, even I know EMM has more features included, should I begin with wso2 MDM?

Comment: from code level, I didn't see that EMM reuse any features provided by wso2 MDM product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 MDM will have the same features as EMM 1.1.0. We have deprecated the WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 product due to some architectural issues. We have stopped all the on-going developments on EMM 1.1.0 branch. MDM 2.0 will be a java application with a pluggable architecture. I suggest you to use MDM 2.0 once its get released. But you can still use EMM 1.1.0 for demo / trial purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will swtich to MDM version

Comment: How can I cannot get a runnable version for MDM2.0? There is no release  available from internet I can download try, right?

Comment: MDM 2.0 has not released yet. But still you can get a MDM milestone 3 from the below link and test it.
https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/prabatha/MDM/2.0.0-M3